# How to use a profiler to see why databinding is slow?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, data-binding, profiler

When I run my application in debug mode, setting the databinding is very slow (about 20 seconds). When I run my application without the debugger, I have no performance issues. It works as expected.

But you can imagine, that when I run the program in debug mode, it is very annoying that everything is so slow. So I was wondering what is causing this. I thought maybe I can do something with the profiler, but I don't know excatly how.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: How are you sure that the `DataBinding` is slow, if you didn't profile it? How did you analyze the situation.?

Comment: I've put the list in a variable and set this variable to the `DataSource` propertty of my bindingsource. I noticed that the latter took a lot of time. `var x = _presenter.GetItems(); bs.DataSource = x;`

Answer (score 0):

I would step into te debugger when it's loading the DataSource. What happens then, do you see it debugging .net framework code?

If you are using sql server I would use [sql server profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
If you don't, but you use nhibernate I would use [nhibernate profiler](http://nhprof.com)

Other tips:

1. remove the .suo and .user-files
2. [cache symbol files](http://dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2009/08/20/Visual-Studio-Debugging-Slow-Try-this!.aspx)